# Use pandas to combine 2 CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 2 csv files containing bathymetry data - single and multibeam

CSV 1 which is the multibeam data looks like:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 626066.4 | 234058.2 | 6.69 |
| 626066.4 | 234059.2 | 6.89 |
| 626066.4 | 234060.2 | 7.06 |

And CSV 2 which contains the singlebeam data looks like:

| x | Y | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 627839 | 232463.4 | 14.22 | 14.46 | 14.71 |
| 627839 | 232463.1 | 14.22 | 14.46 | 14.71 |

I would like to use pandas to merge the 2 CSVs based as follows:

1. The X and Y coordinates of CSV2 are combined with the pre-existing X,Y coordinates of CSV 1
2. The specified Z value of CSV 2 (A, B or C) is combined with CSV 1 Z value

This way I will have a combined xyz dataset of a survey area which will evidentally be more accurate due to a combination of multi and single beam data.

For clarification, what I want to end up with results wise is:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 626066.4 | 234058.2 | 6.69 |
| 626066.4 | 234059.2 | 6.89 |
| 626066.4 | 234060.2 | 7.06 |
| 627839 | 232463.4 | 14.22 |
| 627839 | 232463.1 | 14.22 |

I have tried the below code snippet, but need a way of combining the X's, Y's and Z's based on specified columns of CSV 2.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the files into two dataframes.
df1 = pd.read_csv('CSV1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('CSV2.csv')

# Merge the two dataframes, using _ID column as key
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'X')
df3.set_index('X', inplace = True)

# Write it to a new CSV file
df3.to_csv('CSV3.csv')
```

Comment: can you include sample data, instead of screenshots?

Comment: What do you mean by combined? Added together? Averaged?

Comment: @DNy All records of CSV 2 added beneath CSV 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to be able to tell you function which column is to be handled as `Z` in `df2` and then concat both lists:

```
def concat_df_on_z(df1, df2, z_col):
    df2 = df2[['X', 'Y', z_col]].rename(columns={z_col: 'Z'})
    return pd.concat([df1, df2])

df3 = concat_df_on_z(df1, df2, 'B')
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
          X         Y      Z
0  626066.4  234058.2   6.69
1  626066.4  234059.2   6.89
2  626066.4  234060.2   7.06
0  627839.0  232463.4  14.46
1  627839.0  232463.1  14.46
```

Comment: If I use the script ```import pandas as pd

# Read the files into two dataframes.
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Public/multibeam.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Public/singlebeam.csv')

def concat_df_on_z(df1, df2, z_col):
    df2 = df2[['X', 'Y', z_col]].rename(columns={z_col: 'Z'})
    return pd.concat([df1, df2])

df3 = concat_df_on_z(df1, df2, 'B')
df3.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Public\CSV3.csv')``` I get the below results

Comment: X[m]      Y[m]  Z[m]          X          Y      Z
0      626066.43  234058.2  6.69        NaN        NaN    NaN
1      626066.43  234059.2  6.89        NaN        NaN    NaN
2      626066.43  234060.2  7.06        NaN        NaN    NaN
3      626067.43  234057.2  6.69        NaN        NaN    NaN
4      626067.43  234058.2  6.89        NaN        NaN    NaN
...          ...       ...   ...        ...        ...    ...
34158        NaN       NaN   NaN  627148.40  233739.17  12.94
34159        NaN       NaN   NaN  627148.27  233739.35  12.92

Comment: It's very hard to read as a comment. What is the problem? You can get rid of the index column while writing to csv: `df3.to_csv('CSV3.csv', index=False)`. What are X[m] Y[m] Z[m] ?